# issu DriveApp not move file

Tags: google-apps-script

The following code should create a folder called "prova" inside the folder with id "0B9nV49psIf6LUUJpa0JDZ1dNQnM"

```
function createFolder() {
    var idFolderDestination = "0B9nV49psIf6LUUJpa0JDZ1dNQnM";
    var folderDestination = DriveApp.getFolderById(idFolderDestination);
    var file = folderDestination.createFolder("prova");
}
```

The result of the function is that the folder named "prova" is correctly created but does not move inside the folder with id "0B9nV49psIf6LUUJpa0JDZ1dNQnM". Remains in My Drive.

Answer (score 0):

This was reported as an issues and has since been marked as resolved.